# Java Exam Error Checking

Tags: java

I have the following code from a previous past paper:

```
int n = arr.length; 
double min = 0; 
int minLocation=0; 

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { 
    if( arr[i] < min ) {
        min = arr[i]; 
    }
    minLocation = i; 
} 

System.out.print("The minimal value is arr["); 
System.out.println(minLocation + "] = " + min);
```

I have to answer the following questions from the code:

```
(i) The line on which the error appears 

(ii) What effect the error would have 

(iii) How the error should be corrected. 


You may assume arr[] is a non-empty array of double values that has been 
properly declared and initialized.
```

I know there will be a runtime error at the line with the if statement which i'm still not sure how. As I am unable to correct it I can't see how I get the undesired results. I can see it's such a straight forward question and I am missing out something extremely obvious but I have been looking at it for a while and i'm completely missing it.

Comment: Have you tried to compile and run the code?

Comment: @DanielBarbaria I have put the code into an IDE and as I said I get the arrayindex error for some reason.

Comment: I see your post about a runtime error, nothing about any arrayindex error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in that code. Here a list of them including explanation of impact and how to fix them:

- You are initialising `min` with `0`
  **Effect**: If your array e.g. only consists of `{1.1, 2.2}` your code would claim that 0 is the minimum, what obviously is wrong because there doesn't exist an index i that arr[i] == 0
  **Fix**: `double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;`
- Your for-loop starts at index 1 `for (int i = 1; ...)`
  **Effect**: You are skipping arr[0]
  **Fix**: `for (int i = 0 ...)`
- Your loop iterates once to often because of the condition `or ( ... ; <= n; ...)`
  **Effect**: You will encounter an AIOOBE (`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`)
  **Fix**: `for ( ... ; i < n; ...)`
- Your are overwriting `minLocation` in every iteration of the loop
  **Effect**: After the last iteration of the loop, `minLocation` will always be = n
  **Fix**: Place `minLocation = i;` *inside* the if-statement.

**Corrected version**

```
int      n           = arr.length;
double   min         = Double.MAX_VALUE;
int      minLocation = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(arr[i] < min) {
        min         = arr[i];
        minLocation = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know there will be a runtime error at the line with the if statement
>   which i'm still not sure how

This runtime error will be `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. This error occur because array index is one less than array size.
Your loop should be like.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop needs to be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Otherwise you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` since you access the array outside of its range.

Also you should change your min value initialiaztion to:

```
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
```

Otherwise you will only find the minimum if your array only contains negative values.

Comment: I see now. Such a silly mistake the length is 5 and because it is <= it will go to arr[5] and thats why the array is out of bounds. Thank you

Comment: @GregorKoukkoullis There are several more bugs (see my post)

Answer (score 1):

Did you intend your for() loop to start at index 1? By convention it starts at 0;

It should really be: for(int i=0;i

Answer (score 1):

There are logical errors in your program, if it is intended to find the minimal value and position of given array.

- Initialize

  double min = arr[0];
- End for loop at

  i < n
- Include

  minLocation = i;

as

```
if( arr[i] < min ) 
{
    min = arr[i]; 
    minLocation = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java array indices start at 0. So the for loop should be for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ).
The minimum is only computed if the the elements of the array are non-negative.